# How to concatenate values where NULLs and N/As are present

Tags: t-sql, replace, concatenation, na

I need to concatenate several "entity" related columns in SQL Server. Think something like this...

Region / Subregion / Market / Submarket / Category / Name

Unfortunately, some columns have either N/A or NULLs. Please see example below:

West / California / San Francisco / N/A / NULL/ The Wharf

Instead, I would like to return the following:

West / California / San Francisco / The Wharf

I have the below code; I just am not sure how to handle the slash (/):

```
replace(concat(Region,  ' / ', Subregion, ' / ', Market, ' / ',  Submarket, ' / ',  Category, ' / ',  [Name]), 'N/A', '') as Entity,
```

I returned the following:

West / California / San Francisco / / / The Wharf

Comment: Use `CONCAT_WS` instead and `NULL` (with `NULLIF`) your N/A values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
SELECT 
        REPLACE(
            CONCAT(
                ISNULL(NULLIF(Region, 'N/A'), ''), 
                CASE WHEN Region IS NOT NULL AND Subregion IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' ELSE '' END, 
                ISNULL(NULLIF(Subregion, 'N/A'), ''),
                CASE WHEN (Region IS NOT NULL OR Subregion IS NOT NULL) AND Market IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' ELSE '' END,
                ISNULL(NULLIF(Market, 'N/A'), ''),
                CASE WHEN (Region IS NOT NULL OR Subregion IS NOT NULL OR Market IS NOT NULL) AND Submarket IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' ELSE '' END,
                ISNULL(NULLIF(Submarket, 'N/A'), ''),
                CASE WHEN (Region IS NOT NULL OR Subregion IS NOT NULL OR Market IS NOT NULL OR Submarket IS NOT NULL) AND Category IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' ELSE '' END,
                ISNULL(NULLIF(Category, 'N/A'), ''),
                CASE WHEN (Region IS NOT NULL OR Subregion IS NOT NULL OR Market IS NOT NULL OR Submarket IS NOT NULL OR Category IS NOT NULL) AND [Name] IS NOT NULL THEN ' / ' ELSE '' END,
                ISNULL(NULLIF([Name], 'N/A'), '')
            ), ' / ', ' / '
        ) AS Entity
    FROM MyTable
```

Another way :

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(
        CONCAT_WS(' / ',
            NULLIF(Region, 'N/A'),
            NULLIF(Subregion, 'N/A'),
            NULLIF(Market, 'N/A'),
            NULLIF(Submarket, 'N/A'),
            NULLIF(Category, 'N/A'),
            [Name]
        ), ' / / ', ' / '
    ) AS Entity
FROM MyTable;`
```